# Opencart 2.3 version product.tpl file not show change

Tags: opencart

Opencart 2.3 version
I am changing /catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/product.tpl but not show any change anyone helps me.

Comment: Would you please share the code snippet you're changing/adding. Else its very difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: is there any extension (ocMod or vQMod) installed?

if there is any vQMod then clear its cache by deleting all files from /vqmod/vqcache or if there is any ocMod extension then try to refresh your modification from admin, go to Extensions > Modifications then click on blue button showing on top right corner.